# Jquery:load upload result from iframe

Tags: php, ajax, jquery, iframe

Here is my form

**HTML**

```
<div id="contactus">
     <form action="carrer_.php" method="POST" ENCTYPE="multipart/form-data" class="contactUs" id="send_cv" target="carrer_iframe">
        <label> Name
          <input type="text" name="name"  />
        </label>

        <label> Email
          <input type="text"  name="email" />
        </label>

        <label> Mobile
          <input type="text" class="mobile" name="mobile" />
        </label>

        <label> Cv
           <input type="file" id="cv" name="file" />
        </label>

        <label> Other Info
          <textarea name="message" cols="1" rows="1"></textarea>
        </label>
        <input type="submit" value="send" />
      </form>
      <div id="iframe_result"></div>
      <iframe name="carrer_iframe" id="carrer_iframe" src="carrer_.php" style="width;0;height:0;display:none;" ></iframe>
    </div>
```

**Js**

```
 $('#send_cv').submit( function(){
        $("#carrer_iframe").contents().html("") ;
        $("#iframe_result").load(function(){
                alert( 1 ) ;
                response = $("#carrer_iframe").contents().find("body:last").text();
                alert( response ) ;
                $("#iframe_result").html(response).show();
            });
  } ) ;
```

After submit the form  ( Nothing happened??? )

**How can i get the result from the hidden iframe and alert it && Or what is my error**

Best regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seems to be nothing preventing the form from submitting normally. Try passing the event from the submit function and calling [.preventDefault](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/).

```
$('#send_cv').submit( function(event){
        // Preventing the default form submission action
        event.preventDefault();
        $("#carrer_iframe").contents().html("") ;
        $("#iframe_result").load(function(){
                alert( 1 ) ;
                response = $("#carrer_iframe").contents().find("body:last").text();
                alert( response ) ;
                $("#iframe_result").html(response).show();
            });
  } ) ;
```

**Edit:**

As far as I know .show() only effects the display attribute. Therefore setting the wdith/height to 0 will mean the iframe will never show.

Comment: after I did this , the form not submit any thing , what do you think ??

Comment: Remove the width:0 and height:0 from the iframe style. The display:none will suffice